# Catching HttpWebRequest Timeout

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, timeout, webrequest, httpwebresponse

```
public int loginEmail(string email, string password)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        string responseStr = null;
        string Email = email;
        string Pass = password;

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        string postData = "PostData";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1000;
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
        request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                responseStr = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return 1;
        }

        string[] cooktemp;
        string[] seperatortemp = new string[] { ";" };
        cooktemp = responseStr.Split(seperatortemp, StringSplitOptions.None);

        LoginHeaders[0] = cooktemp[0] + ";";

        return 0;
    }
```

This code runs just fine, but sometimes the request does not get a response back. When the request doesn't get a response back the program will hang and then finally it will give a timeout error that crashes the program. All I am trying to do right now is just catch the timeout error so I can handle it, but nothing seems to be catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely timing out in `GetRequestStream()`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) specifically states that it may throw `WebException` if the time-out period for the request expired.

So include that block of code inside your try/catch and you should be able to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but an issue which I also hit today.

What I didn't realise is that if you have a web service which, say, attempts to write to a file which is *locked*... then having the code in a simple `try..catch` is not enough.

You must specifically have a `catch` which handles `WebExceptions`.

```
try
{
    //  Run your web service code
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //  Handle a WebException, such as trying to write to a "locked" file on the network
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //  Handle a regular Exception
}
```

I always thought that a `WebException` was a type of `Exception`, so these would get caught by this `catch` handler:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //  Handle a regular Exception
}
```

It doesn't.

So to avoid your code throwing "**Request timed out**" messages, with no suggestion about what caused them, do remember to add these second `catch` handler.

Btw, on my [web services tutorial](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm), here's the code I recommend, which looks out for Exceptions, and returns them in the Response header:

```
try
{
    //  Put your code in here
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //  Return any exception messages back to the Response header
    OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
    response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    response.StatusDescription = ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "");
    return null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //  Return any exception messages back to the Response header
    OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
    response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    response.StatusDescription = ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: System.Net.WebException]

```
try { ... }            
catch (System.Net.WebException sne)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(req.Timeout.ToString());
        }
```

I think the timeout will always be "5000" no matter what.
If you tell it "timeout is 5 seconds" it will always try for 5 seconds before giving up.