# HttpWebRequest returns null if status != 200

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a function that test a given url and get the status code,
the issue is that HttpWebRequest variable will return NULL - as commented in the code - if the status is tineOut or url could not be reached while it supposed to return **408** for timeOut.

```
try
{
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); //set http request
    request.Timeout = timeOut * 1000;
    request.ContinueTimeout = timeOut * 1000;

    stopwatch.Start(); //start timer
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //this will return NULL if URL is timedOut or not reachable
    response.Close(); //close session 
    stopwatch.Stop(); //Stop timer

    statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode; //save status code as int
    info[0] = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString(); //store Latency to info
    info[1] = statusCode.ToString(); //store status code
    info[2] = response.StatusDescription; //store status description 
}
catch (WebException err) //catch timeOut case
{
    stopwatch.Stop();

    var responseObj = err.Response as HttpWebResponse; //err.Response is NULL as well.
    info[0] = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString(); //store Latency to info
    info[1] = (int)responseObj.StatusCode + "";//store status code
    info[2] = responseObj.StatusDescription; //store status description 
}
```

Finally, i couldn't apply these two solutions to my current code while they seems to be same as my issue.
[How to define a more aggressive timeout for HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838088/how-to-define-a-more-aggressive-timeout-for-httpwebrequest/)

[Catching HttpWebRequest Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634249/catching-httpwebrequest-timeout)

Inform me if any clarification is needed please.

Comment: What do you mean with "returns null"? What exactly is null? The response? Because that's not returned by HttpWebRequest but by its `.Response` property.

Comment: @Nyerguds i had edited the question, the line response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); will return null

Comment: Uh. Shouldn't the timeout throw an exception? You should never read that object in that case.

Comment: You're not assigning `response` in the exception handler, but `responseObj`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Fair point, but he's also not using `response` to get his data out in that case.

Comment: @Omar - Please accept an answer or some issue with the answer that we can address.

Comment: @Archlight i just resume my work today, will deploy your answer to my code and update you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

request.GetResponse() returns the response from the webserver you are trying to communicate with.

Now when you have a timeout or bad URL the response from the webserver will be NULL because you haven't got any information from that server.

You can detect the timeout by using the status you get from the WebException.

Here is a general catch block for your http communication. Note that your 408 is actually not correct and any other problems that are not http related will end up as -1.

```
catch (WebException wbEx)
{
    if (wbEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        if (wbEx.Response is HttpWebResponse response)
        {
            returnStatusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;
        }
        else // should not happen
        {
            returnStatusCode = -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (wbEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
        {
            returnStatusCode = 408; // now this is not right because this is CLIENT timeout.
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    returnStatusCode =  -1;
}
```

Comment: let us assume that request supposed to have 500 status, how could i handle this ?

Comment: Your http 500 is internal server error, and the message is sent from the webserver hat had that error. And therefore you get an http status from that in your response.

Comment: @Nyerguds it supposed to handle as i expected, but it can't return status code as Integer info[1] = (int)responseObj.StatusCode + "";

Comment: Use proper null check and `ToString()` instead of that `+ ""` nonsense. And what do you mean with "can't"? Does it give an exception? This isn't even the line you were talking about; this is in the `catch` block.

Comment: @Nyerguds yes you are totally right I'm still talking about the line i mentioned in my question but responseObj in our case will hold err.Response value which is NULL as well!!
while err.Message = "The operation has timed out". did you got my point ?

Comment: Omar- use WebExceptionStatus.Timeout for detecting if it has timed out.

Comment: @Omar You don't need the response. For errors, _the exception itself_ contains a `Status` property.

Comment: @Archlight there is multiple errors appear in Line 5 "`if (wbEx.Response is HttpWebResponse response)`"  expect: **), ;, } and }**

Comment: @Archlight i solved the error by deleting `response` from if statement and reassign it before. but still the `wbEx` response is null when i test the code to request a 404 page.

Comment: @Archlight it works with your code, i discovered that null issue was due to TimeOut property that i set in `WebRequest` variable.